# Some basic questions about geometrical notations

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis

I have some questions about the notations of geometry.

(i) $z\in [0,5]^2\cap \mathbb{Z}^2$ is different from $z\in [0,5]^2$?

(ii) Fix a subset $A\subset [0,n]^2$. If $[0,n]^2\cap A \subset B(0, Cn)$ for some constants $C>0$ where $B(0, Cn)$ is a ball with radius $Cn$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, can we conclude that $[0,n]^2\subset B(0, Cn)?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) Yes, the two are different. $z = (z_1,z_2)\in [0,5]^2 \cap \mathbb Z^2$ requires both $z_1$ and $z_2$ to be **integers**, in the interval $[0,5].$ While $z= (z_1,z_2)\in [0,5]^2$ places no restrictions on $z_1,z_2$ except that they must both lie in the interval $[0,5]$.

If you want an example, $(1.5, 2.7) \notin [0,5]^2 \cap \mathbb Z^2$ but $(1,2) \in [0,5]^2 \cap \mathbb Z^2$. $(1.5, 2.7) \in [0,5]^2$, though.

(ii) Short answer: No, your conclusion is incorrect. Here's a counterexample. We fix $A\subset [0,4]^2$ (I've picked $n = 4$, and $A = [0,2]^2$ in the figure below). So, $A \cap [0,4]^2 = A$. Hence, $[0,4]^2 \cap A\subset B(0,4C)$ tells us nothing more than $A\subset B(0,4C)$ for some $C>0$. I've picked $4C = \sqrt{10}$, i.e. $C = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{4} > 0$. Clearly, $A = [0,2]^2\subset B(0,4C)$ but parts of $[0,4]^2$ lie outside $B(0,4C)$. I've assuming that by $B(x,r)$ you're referring to the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x\in\mathbb R^2$. For the purpose of this question, it doesn't really matter whether $B(x,r)$ is the open ball or the closed ball.

[image]